# mount() function doesn't accept parameters in Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Components;

use Livewire\Component;

class PropertyCard extends Component
{

    public $title;

    public function mount($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.components.property-card');
    }
}
```

This is Livewire controller

```
<livewire:components.property-card title="Test 1" />
```

This livewire component.

Error is
Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $title ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\Components\PropertyCard (View: D:\Projects\Laravel\clemsonporter.com\resources\views\livewire\new-launch-page.blade.php)

Comment: Looks fine to me, do you have `<livewire:components.property-card />` someplace on that page without `title` on it perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have missed a double colon (:) before `title`.

```html
<livewire:components.property-card :title="Test 1"/>
```

Read more on parameters [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Public properties dont need to be set in mount. Livewire will automatically detect them. The following snippet does exactly the same as your code:

```
class PropertyCard extends Component
{
    public $title;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.components.property-card');
    }
}
```

But that's besides the error you're experiencing. [Qirel is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370413/mount-function-doesnt-accept-parameters-in-livewire#comment129572880_73370413), there's some component where you aren't setting the title property.